# Two way communication between server and client on socket.io node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write code for server in node.js in which, client running on browser will send some data to server when some ".on" event will occur. Now at server side the task is to receive data coming from client and send that data back to client.

I am using socket.io.
Write now I am doing this as,
Client side:

```
<p id="ValSlider1"> Curr Val </p>
<input class = "mySlider1" type="range" name="slider" id="slider-0" value="0" min="0"     max="100" />

<script>

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');

$(".mySlider1").change(function() {
var sVal = $(this).val();
socket.emit('ValSlider1', sVal);
console.log('ValSlider1: ' + sVal );
});

socket.on('packet', function (data) {
var valFromServer = data.split('-');

document.getElementById("ValSlider1").innerHTML =   valFromServer[0];
document.getElementById("ValSlider2").innerHTML =   valFromServer[1];
document.getElementById("ValSlider3").innerHTML =   valFromServer[2];
document.getElementById("ValSlider4").innerHTML =   valFromServer[3];

$('#container1').html(data);
});
```

and on server side:

```
var qs = require('querystring'),
fs = require('fs'),
parser = new require('xml2json'),
urr = require('url'),
app= require('http').createServer(handler).listen(3000),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

function handler (req, res) {
var reqObj = urr.parse(req.url, true);
var reqPath = reqObj.pathname;
if ('/' == reqPath ) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client.html', function(err, data) {if     (err)                   {res.writeHead(500);
return res.end('Errorloadingclient.html');
}
res.end(data);
});
} 
};

var slider1, slider2, slider3, slider4 ;

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

socket.on('ValSlider1', function(data){
slider1 = data ;
socket.emit('packet', data);
console.log("Slider 1 Value: " + data);
}); 
});

setInterval(function () {
var data = slider1 + "-" + slider2 + "-" + slider3 + "-"    + slider4; 
socket.emit('packet', data);
console.log(data);
},1000);
});
app.maxConnections = 1;
```

Now, when communication starts initially two-three slider change values are received by server and printed on console but then the values not get updated, server sends previous values only to client.
Also, if I use  socket.emit('ValSlider1', sVal); twice at client side it works better, but why it require emit twice  am unable to find, any help will appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this tutorial http://www.williammora.com/2013/03/nodejs-tutorial-building-chatroom-with.html

Comment: @meagar That doesn't make the question any less valid.  Provide an answer.

Comment: @meagar You don't know that ashok didn't attempt to research this.  My guess is that an attempt was made.  I don't think this question is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to do it in this way:

On server side:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler).listen(3000),
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3001);
var publisher = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

On client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');
var socket2 = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

The client will send data to server on 'socket'. In response, the server will also send some data on the same port. The server will continuously push data on port 3001 at every second which is received in the client with the ".on('data')" event of server1.